# Push variable outside nested functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm not sure why this isn't working so if anyone can help that would be great.  I have nested functions and I wand to push the value returned by the firebase query and re use it in another firebase query, and then again, in a loop.  Its essentially a poor man's infinite scroll.  Nonetheless, I cannot get the value of the "arr" variable into the "numWanted" array outside so I can use it again in the next loop. What can I do to achieve the desired result?

Also, I have have beed trying to make the inner variables global, and push them out to another variable but that doesn't seem to work.  Possible that I am just doing it wrong?

Thanks in advance..

```
$scope.loadMoreData = function() {
  var numWanted = [];
  console.log(numWanted);
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref('products')
    .orderByChild('rank')
    .startAt(0)
    .endAt(numWanted)
    .limitToLast(3)
    .once('value', function(products) {
      products.forEach(function(product) {
        var product = {
          rank: product.val().rank
        };

        arr = product.rank;
      });
      numWanted.push(arr);
      console.log(numWanted);
    });
};
```

P.S. I realize this code doesn't actually work as you cannot use an array in a firebase query.  My plan is to extract the number I need once the array has been populated.

Answer (score 1):

You have a conflict with your parameter named product and a local variable named product.  You need to rename one of those.